# Recorrer un arrary en PHP Multidimensional

Tags: php, array, bucles

tengo el siguiente código:

```
$materias = $Alumnos->getMaterias($_GET['IdGrado'], $IdAsignacion, $_GET['IdUnidad']);
```

Ese código con var_dump() me devuelve lo siguiente:

```
array(1) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(11) {
    [0]=>
    array(5) {
      ["IdCuadro"]=>
      string(17) "CUA-5e31d1272b444"
      ["Estado"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["Materia"]=>
      string(22) "Artes Plásticas"
      ["Nombres"]=>
      string(19) "María Isabel"
      ["Apellidos"]=>
      string(11) "Soliz Mutaz"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(5) {
      ["IdCuadro"]=>
      string(17) "CUA-5e3c26d5190ec"
      ["Estado"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["Materia"]=>
      string(18) "Computación"
      ["Nombres"]=>
      string(13) "Evelyn Isaura"
      ["Apellidos"]=>
      string(23) "Arévalo Alvarado"
    }
    [2]=>
    array(5) {
      ["IdCuadro"]=>
      string(17) "CUA-5e52e316daec1"
      ["Estado"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["Materia"]=>
      string(30) "Educación Física"
      ["Nombres"]=>
      string(7) "Martina"
      ["Apellidos"]=>
      string(13) "Macario Xaper"
    }
  }
}
```

Necesito recorrer esa variable $materias para armar una tabla html, pero no encuentro cómo hacer ese proceso, alguna idea, muchas gracias. Ya he usado foreach pero creo que no lo estoy aplicando bien.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes recorrerlo con for o foreach entrando al atributo data

```
foreach($materias['data'] as $materia) {
    echo $materia['IdCuadro'];
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, estaba fácil, no había agregado ['data'] en el foreach.